# Dapper & TransactionScope?

Tags: transactionscope, dapper

I just started playing around with Dapper. So far i love it. Does dapper not work with `TransactionScope`? I noticed that even if i never call `TransactionScope.Complete` then my changes are still committed to the database. If TransactionScope isn't supported now is there any plans in the future to support it? If not then you have to use traditional transaction management (System.Transactions.Transaction)?

Update: I just talked to Sam over Twitter. It should work. I'll update it tomorrow morning (at work) with the details to see if anyone can figure out why my changes were still being committed to the db even when i never called complete.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

It was totally my fault and not fully understanding transactionscope. A connection is not automatically enlisted in transactionscope unless you open the connection within the transactionscope:

***Automatic Enlistment***

```
  using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
  {
      con.Open();                                
      //update/delete/insert commands here
      ...
      scope.Complete();
  }
```

***Manual Enlistment***

```
    con.Open();
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
       con.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current);  
       //update/delte/insert statements here
       ...
       scope.Complete();
    }
```

Details can be found here: [Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884863/under-what-circumstances-is-an-sqlconnection-automatically-enlisted-in-an-ambient)

Comment: With automatic, I get 'Enlisting in Ambient transactions is not supported.'

Comment: ... might be a .net core issue.

Comment: @IanWarburtoni think it probably is. See here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23927

Comment: Aren't you supposed to call scope.Complete() ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53698092/3606250

Comment: @drizin yes but that is just a small code snippet not a full example.

Comment: @coding4fun Thanks. Yet, I suggest to add `scope.Complete()` to the snippet, since it's fundamental part of the TransactionScope usage pattern, and other developers might copy your snippet without that necessary part.