# Proper way of using BeginTransaction with Dapper.IDbConnection

Tags: c#, .net, orm, dapper, idbconnection

Which is the proper way of using `BeginTransaction()` with `IDbConnection` in Dapper ?

I have created a method in which i have to use `BeginTransaction()`. Here is the code.

```
using (IDbConnection cn = DBConnection)
{
    var oTransaction = cn.BeginTransaction();

    try
    {
        // SAVE BASIC CONSULT DETAIL
        var oPara = new DynamicParameters();
        oPara.Add("@PatientID", iPatientID, dbType: DbType.Int32);
        ..........blah......blah............
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        oTransaction.Rollback();
        return new SaveResponse { Success = false, ResponseString = ex.Message };
    }
}
```

When i executed above method - i got an exception -

> Invalid operation. The connection is closed.

This is because you can't begin a transaction before the connection is opened. So when i add this line: `cn.Open();`, the error gets resolved. But i have read somewhere that manually opening the connection is **bad practice!!** Dapper opens a connection only when it needs to.

In Entity framework you can handle a transaction using a `TransactionScope`.

So my question is what is a good practice to handle transaction without adding the line `cn.Open()...` in **Dapper** ? I guess there should be some proper way for this.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Manually opening a connection is not "bad practice"; dapper works with open or closed connections *as a convenience*, nothing more. A common gotcha is people having connections that are left open, unused, for too long without ever releasing them to the pool - however, this isn't a problem in most cases, and you can certainly do:

```
using(var cn = CreateConnection()) {
    cn.Open();
    using(var tran = cn.BeginTransaction()) {
        try {
            // multiple operations involving cn and tran here

            tran.Commit();
        } catch {
            tran.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that dapper has an optional parameter to pass in the transaction, for example:

```
cn.Execute(sql, args, transaction: tran);
```

I am actually *tempted* to make extension methods on `IDbTransaction` that work similarly, since [a transaction always exposes `.Connection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbtransaction%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); this would allow:

```
tran.Execute(sql, args);
```

But this does not exist today.

`TransactionScope` is another option, but has different semantics: this could involve the LTM or DTC, depending on ... well, luck, mainly. It is also tempting to create a wrapper around `IDbTransaction` that doesn't need the `try`/`catch` - more like how `TransactionScope` works; something like (this also does not exist):

```
using(var cn = CreateConnection())
using(var tran = cn.SimpleTransaction())
{
    tran.Execute(...);
    tran.Execute(...);

    tran.Complete();
}
```

Comment: FFR: this was suggested but rejected as a PR :( https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/pull/429
Marc also participated in the discussion. It was rejected mainly because there is already duplication between sync/async - adding extension methods for transactions would result in all methods being duplicated 4 times.

Comment: @marc-gravell - In the case of rollback, do you have to explicitly call `tran.RollBack`? is the transaction not rolled back automatically on dispose?

Answer (score 6):

You should not call

```
cn.Close();
```

because the using block will try to close too. 
For the transaction part, yes you can use TransactionScope as well, since it is not an Entity Framework related technique.
Have a look at this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6874617/566608
It explain how to enlist your connection in the transaction scope.
The important aspect is: **connection are automatically enlisted in the transaction IIF you open the connection inside the scope**.

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry i forgot to remove it. So the link you provided said that you can use TransactionScope with Dapper but you have to write this code - **con.Open()**. So is it a good practice ??

Comment: of course you have to open the connection before using it

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Tim Schreiber](https://github.com/timschreiber/DapperUnitOfWork) solution which is simple yet powerful and implemented using repository pattern and has `Dapper Transactions` in mind.

The `Commit()` in the code below shows it.

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private IDbConnection _connection;
    private IDbTransaction _transaction;
    private IBreedRepository _breedRepository;
    private ICatRepository _catRepository;
    private bool _disposed;

    public UnitOfWork(string connectionString)
    {
        _connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        _connection.Open();
        _transaction = _connection.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public IBreedRepository BreedRepository
    {
        get { return _breedRepository ?? (_breedRepository = new BreedRepository(_transaction)); }
    }

    public ICatRepository CatRepository
    {
        get { return _catRepository ?? (_catRepository = new CatRepository(_transaction)); }
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        try
        {
            _transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            _transaction.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            _transaction.Dispose();
            _transaction = _connection.BeginTransaction();
            resetRepositories();
        }
    }

    private void resetRepositories()
    {
        _breedRepository = null;
        _catRepository = null;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if(disposing)
            {
                if (_transaction != null)
                {
                    _transaction.Dispose();
                    _transaction = null;
                }
                if(_connection != null)
                {
                    _connection.Dispose();
                    _connection = null;
                }
            }
            _disposed = true;
        }
    }

    ~UnitOfWork()
    {
        dispose(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its nice. Have several questions about the solution. What if dont wanna use transactions lets say for usual select queries? So, as I understood, sql will generate code for transactions after commit() or what? Why do I need do BeginTransaction() if I will not use it in query? Can it affect perfomance for queries where I dont need transactions? Please, dont understand me wrong. I just wanna clarify all things before I start use this in production.

Comment: So, I think that better is to add flag (useTransaction = false). In that case, creating instance of unitOfWork we can chose strategy that we need. Am I right?

Comment: You don't need to `commit()` when your query is just `SELECT`. So don't worry about performance!. your idea about adding a flag is nice but in fact, it is not necessary. I use it this way and it works like a charm.

Comment: Could you explain why _transaction is disposed in the finally block although _transaction.RollBack() has been called in the catch block?

Comment: @EfeZaladin `finally` block will run for sure, so disposing of the object is neccessary either way. In case of successful `try`, the `_transaction` should dispose and if something goes wrong, `_transaction` should be rollbacked and in both scenarios, it will be disposed of finally.

Comment: @vaheeds Thanks! It's obvious but I think I saw your answer at a late hour :D I also have an idea and I would like to know it makes sense. Could we open the connection and begin the transaction when a repository's get method is called for the first time, in order not to hog the DB connections when not necessary?

Comment: @EfeZaladin Generally, you don't need transactions for read-only queries like `get`. When you're going to perform some single or batch `write` queries like insert, update or delete, in a row, you will need to begin a `transaction` to have the ability to roll back in case of any error occurs.

Comment: @vaheeds No I mean the getter-setter methods. Eg: private ICatRepository _catRepository

Answer (score -1):

There are two intended ways to use transactions with Dapper.

1. Pass your `IDbTranasction` to your normal Dapper call.

   **Before:**

   ```
   var affectedRows = connection.Execute(sql, new {CustomerName = "Mark"});
   ```

   **After:**

   ```
   var affectedRows = connection.Execute(sql, new {CustomerName = "Mark"}, transaction=tx);
   ```
2. Use the new `.Execute` extension method that Dapper adds to `IDbTransaction` itself:

   ```
   tx.Execute(sql, new {CustomerName = "Mark"});
   ```

**Note**: the variable `tx` comes from `IDbTransaction tx = connection.BeginTransaction();`

This is how you're supposed to use transactions with Dapper; neither of them are TranasctionScope.

### Bonus Reading

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/67474832/12597