# Is it possible to use System.Transactions.TransactionScope with SqlBulkCopy?

Tags: .net, sql-server, transactionscope, sqlbulkcopy

Very simple question: is it possible to use `System.Transactions.TransactionScope` together with `SqlBulkCopy`? The documentation [Transaction and Bulk Copy Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tchktcdk%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) doesn't mention anything (at least as of .NET 4.0) and my testing indicates it does not automatically enlist with `TransactionScope`.

Comment: Here is some answers about TransactionScope that can be helpful to your situation http://stackoverflow.com/q/2884863/463478

Answer (score 55):

`SqlBulkCopy` never enlists into a transaction. `SqlCommand` also does not do that. Common misconception. The enlistment is performed at the time `SqlConnection.Open` is called. After that, anything that runs on that connection is part of the transaction implicitly. In fact it is no longer *allowed* to pass an explicit transaction.

If you want `SqlBulkCopy` to take part in a `System.Transactions.Transaction` using `TransactionScope` the transaction must be set at the time you open the connection.

It is very easy to do:

```
using (var tran = new TransactionScope(...))
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
  conn.Open(); //This enlists.

  using (var sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn)) {
    sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(...);
  }

  tran.Complete(); //Commit.
}
```

This code is all you need. Possible mistakes:

1. The transaction must be opened early enough.
2. Do not use the `SqlTransaction` parameter of `SqlBulkCopy`. Pass `null`.
3. Do not use `SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction`.
4. Do not add exception handling unless you want to actually do something. Rollback is automatic if there is no commit.
5. Use the `using` statement for clean code and deterministic cleanup. Do not manually close or dispose any of these objects unless you have to. This would be redundant.

You can use any batch size you like and all batches will be part of the transaction. Therefore, batching has limited value (in particular the transaction log cannot be truncated early). Try no batching at all first.

Answer (score 4):

To perform atomic SqlBulkCopy imports that span across all batches (and, optionally, across other database statements) we need to use transactions. The following steps outline the process of using a transaction with SqlBulkCopy:

1. Create a SqlConnection to the destination database server.
2. Open the connection.
3. Create a SqlTransaction object.
4. Create the SqlBulkCopy object passing in the SqlTransaction object
   into the constructor.
5. Perform the import - the call to WriteToServer - within a
   Try...Catch block.
       If the operation completes, commit the transaction; if it fails, roll it back.

[Using Transactions with SqlBulkCopy](https://web.archive.org/web/20211016211619/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/111109-1.aspx)

Comment: What is we have two databases involved?

Comment: This answer does not explain TransactionScope which was asked.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to define the transaction in a bulk load (to my knowledge) is to specify the batchsize.

The advantage of the bulk load is that you get a bulk update lock (multi-threaded read and a multi-threaded write). You get this when using bcp, bulk insert, a ssis data flow task with (tablock), a insert(columns)select columns from openrowset (bulk), or a sqlbulkcopy. This is handy when trying to minimize both the time to load and the transaction log size (only if you have satisfied the minimally logged requirements, which will save you hours on millions of rows).

Anytime you load data, the transaction log is going to be the bottleneck. If time is of the essence, it's important to minimize how much gets logged.

Once the batchsize is satisfied (the number of rows that you specified to commit on) the transaction gets committed and starts over. If you specify a batchsize of 0, the transaction will cover the entire file and rollback if any data issues arise.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I have single-row commits and bulk loads into *multiple* tables followed by a single-row update in another table that have to all succeed or none succeed. I was hoping it would be easy to accomplish wrapping the commits and bulk loads and final update in one `TransactionScope`. I'll just have to take a different approach. Thanks for the detailed answer, much appreciated.