# Can I use SqlBulkCopy inside Transaction

Tags: c#, sql, transactions

Is it safe to use `SqlBulkCopy` in a `TransactionScope`? I am aware of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313967/is-it-possible-to-use-system-transactions-transactionscope-with-sqlbulkcopy) but it does not answer the question and its pretty old. If its not possible what is a good alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that if the `TransactionScope` is created before the sql-connection used for the `SqlBulkCopy` is created and opened the transaction-handling mechanics of the `TransactionScope` are used. Which means that you manually need to create your own `SqlConnection` and open it which you later use for the `SqlBulkCopy` instance.

```
using (var ts = new TransactionScope())
using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(conStr))
{
  sqlCon.Open(); // ensure to open it before SqlBulkCopy can open it in another transactionscope.
  using (var bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlCon))
  {
    // Do you stuff
    bulk.WriteToServer...
  }      

  ts.Complete(); // finish the transaction, ie commit
}
```

**Note 1**:
Changed answer heavily after reading up a bit on `TransactionScope` vs `SqlTransaction`

**Note 2**:
This answer is purely from reading, I have no empirical evidence of the above as of now.

**Note 3**:
There seems to be a new answer in the question you were referring to since my first reply, he gives the same answer as I do here, so I hope he has empirical evidence :) (ie https://stackoverflow.com/a/33311494/691294)

Comment: How do I get a transaction object from a TransactionScope?

Comment: @Luke101 You cannot easily do that, if at all, but it seems like opening your `SqlConnection` inside a `TransactionScope` does the same thing. See my updated answer for details.