# Bulk inserts taking longer than expected using Dapper

Tags: performance, sqlbulkcopy, dapper

After reading [this article](https://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/170502/Indepth_SQL_Server__High_performance_inserts.php) I decided to take a closer look at the way I was using Dapper.

I ran this code on an empty database

```
var members = new List<Member>();
for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
{
    members.Add(new Member()
    {
        Username = i.toString(),
        IsActive = true
    });
}

using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    connection.Execute(@"
insert Member(Username, IsActive)
values(@Username, @IsActive)", members);

    scope.Complete();
}
```

it took about 20 seconds. That's 2500 inserts/second. Not bad, but not great either considering the blog was achieving 45k inserts/second. Is there a more efficient way to do this in Dapper?

Also, as a side note, running this code through the Visual Studio debugger took **over 3 minutes!** I figured the debugger would slow it down a little, but I was really surprised to see that much.

**UPDATE**

So this

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    connection.Execute(@"
insert Member(Username, IsActive)
values(@Username, @IsActive)", members);

    scope.Complete();
}
```

and this

```
    connection.Execute(@"
insert Member(Username, IsActive)
values(@Username, @IsActive)", members);
```

both took 20 seconds.

But this took 4 seconds!

```
SqlTransaction trans = connection.BeginTransaction();

connection.Execute(@"
insert Member(Username, IsActive)
values(@Username, @IsActive)", members, transaction: trans);

trans.Commit();
```

Comment: Have you tried a DbTransaction (SqlTransaction)? That is a bit less overhead. Also, just for numbers: maybe try it without a transaction too, so we know what we are measuring. Finally, what does the 20s span? The inserts? The inserts+complete? Everything? Something else?

Comment: 20s is just the part encompassed by the using statement. I'll try the SqlTransaction

Comment: The different transaction type can't shave off more that a few milliseconds. It is a one-time cost, not proportional to the number of items.

Comment: @usr all I'm saying is: it would be nice to be able to say thaT based on having the numbers

Comment: edited an update. I'm a little surprised at the result, but it is what it is. i've run the 3 approaches twice each with empty databases, same results each time.

Comment: Benchmark your SqlTransaction version against a raw SqlCommand/SqlTransaction one on your machine. You need to be comparing the apples to apples. Also do a warmup round of 1 insert prior to measuring anything.

Comment: TransactionScope does a bunch of DTC nonsense you generally do not care about, would avoid it unless I needed that feature, it is quite easy to roll your own context attached to thread local storage

Comment: Just converted another method I had that took 21 minutes to do 425k inserts, now it does it in 55 seconds. <3

Comment: @qntmfred 12500/s isn't a bad effort ;p Since you've done all the work, I would suggest you self-answer this - it seems like using the explicit connection-based transaction is the trick for optimum performance. I am actually surprised it out-performs *not* using a transaction, but: evidence is evidence, data is data.

Comment: @MarcGravell I think he is using a transaction, just not using transactionscope that does all the dtc nonsense

Comment: @MarcGravell note, even SqlTransaction has some additional overhead over "begin tran"

Comment: hey guys, just wondering why is it slower when running it in VS Debugger? is this captured somewhere on the Dapper page? thanks

Comment: And what would the performance be if the connection was opened within the TransactionScope as per the MSDN example?

Comment: @MarcGravell i have three properties in my object  class  and i want to insert into two properties in query. then what to do in that case?

Comment: @MarcGravell for example Member class is having three properties Username,IsActive and email . i am having list of member class objects and i want to insert only Username and IsActive

Comment: Original article link is broken - @kenwarner, is http://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/170502/Indepth_SQL_Server__High_performance_inserts.php a reprint?

Comment: Don't use TransactionScope when you can use a native database transaction!

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The best I was able to achieve was 50k records in 4 seconds using this approach

```
SqlTransaction trans = connection.BeginTransaction();

connection.Execute(@"
insert Member(Username, IsActive)
values(@Username, @IsActive)", members, transaction: trans);

trans.Commit();
```

Comment: maybe the connection isnt enlisted in transaction and you got the problem before?

Comment: @Parhs: that's a 50% improvement. </pedantic>

Comment: I am just curious, why you put your code under transaction? What's difference if we don't use transaction in this case?

Comment: @skolima Although, you can phrase it "3 records per minute" to "6 records per minute" (or any equivelant amount), then it's a 100% improvement

Comment: @CuongLe I'd imagine he want's the bulk insert as a whole to be atomic. Otherwise, there isn't a need to have a transaction (a single insert, if it fails would throw an exception that would halt the execution)

Comment: Hii, I used the same code, I'm inserting 100000 records, but it's taking 62 sec. but you are saying 50000 records took only 4 sec. [code](http://i.stack.imgur.com/suVUV.png) . Can you please what's wrong I'm doing here.

Comment: Not sure if it's a change in Dapper or just how I use it but I had to use `IDbTransaction trans = con.BeginTransaction();`. I saw a 60 times performance increase for 200,000 entries that have a PK.

Comment: @AmitKumar inserts depends hugely on how many indexes you have on your table, also the physical speed of your storage medium.

Comment: @ErikBergstedt: In my table, It does not have any other(`non-clustered`) index except only 1 `clustered` index on PK. So It should not take that much time. I still could not find any way to reduce time, so I'm asking.

Comment: @AmitKumar interesting, what type of harddrive do you use? does anyone else use this drive?

Comment: guys - I just looked at sql server profiler and I'm puzzled. this code doesn't do batching (at least for me) - it inserts one row per operation (meaning 1500 rows - 1500 separate insert commands). I use Sql Server 2012 with latest dapper

Comment: @chester89 I agree with you. This isn't bulk inserting anything. It's just regular inserts. I don't think dapper can handle bulk inserts at this point

Comment: Tim Corey has a good video including bulk inserts (no Dapper can't do it): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eKkh5Xm0OlU&t=12s

Comment: What about the case when you need rows' ids?

Answer (score 14):

I stumbled accross this recently and noticed that the TransactionScope is created after the connection is opened (I assume this since Dappers Execute doesn't open the connection, unlike Query). According to the answer Q4 here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2886326/455904 that will not result in the connection to be handled by the TransactionScope. My workmate did some quick tests, and opening the connection outside the TransactionScope drastically decreased performance.

So changing to the following should work:

```
// Assuming the connection isn't already open
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    connection.Open();
    connection.Execute(@"
insert Member(Username, IsActive)
values(@Username, @IsActive)", members);

    scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: If you try to `ExecuteAsync`, this will throw an exception: "A TransactionScope must be disposed on the same thread that it was created". To avoid this: `using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))`

Answer (score 6):

I created an extension method that would allow you to do a bulk insert very quickly.

```
public static class DapperExtensions
{
    public static async Task BulkInsert<T>(
        this IDbConnection connection,
        string tableName,
        IReadOnlyCollection<T> items,
        Dictionary<string, Func<T, object>> dataFunc)
    {
        const int MaxBatchSize = 1000;
        const int MaxParameterSize = 2000;

        var batchSize = Math.Min((int)Math.Ceiling((double)MaxParameterSize / dataFunc.Keys.Count), MaxBatchSize);
        var numberOfBatches = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)items.Count / batchSize);
        var columnNames = dataFunc.Keys;
        var insertSql = $"INSERT INTO {tableName} ({string.Join(", ", columnNames.Select(e => $"[{e}]"))}) VALUES ";
        var sqlToExecute = new List<Tuple<string, DynamicParameters>>();

        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfBatches; i++)
        {
            var dataToInsert = items.Skip(i * batchSize)
                .Take(batchSize);
            var valueSql = GetQueries(dataToInsert, dataFunc);

            sqlToExecute.Add(Tuple.Create($"{insertSql}{string.Join(", ", valueSql.Item1)}", valueSql.Item2));
        }

        foreach (var sql in sqlToExecute)
        {
            await connection.ExecuteAsync(sql.Item1, sql.Item2, commandTimeout: int.MaxValue);
        }
    }

    private static Tuple<IEnumerable<string>, DynamicParameters> GetQueries<T>(
        IEnumerable<T> dataToInsert,
        Dictionary<string, Func<T, object>> dataFunc)
    {
        var parameters = new DynamicParameters();

        return Tuple.Create(
            dataToInsert.Select(e => $"({string.Join(", ", GenerateQueryAndParameters(e, parameters, dataFunc))})"),
            parameters);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GenerateQueryAndParameters<T>(
        T entity,
        DynamicParameters parameters,
        Dictionary<string, Func<T, object>> dataFunc)
    {
        var paramTemplateFunc = new Func<Guid, string>(guid => $"@p{guid.ToString().Replace("-", "")}");
        var paramList = new List<string>();

        foreach (var key in dataFunc)
        {
            var paramName = paramTemplateFunc(Guid.NewGuid());
            parameters.Add(paramName, key.Value(entity));
            paramList.Add(paramName);
        }

        return paramList;
    }
}
```

Then to use this extension method, you would write code like the following:

```
await dbConnection.BulkInsert(
    "MySchemaName.MyTableName",
    myCollectionOfItems,
    new Dictionary<string, Func<MyObjectToInsert, object>>
        {
            { "ColumnOne", u => u.ColumnOne },
            { "ColumnTwo", u => u.ColumnTwo },
            ...
        });
```

This is quite primitive and has further room for improvement, such as passing in a transaction or a commandTimeout value but it does the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found all these examples incomplete.

Here is some code that properly closes the connection after use, and also correctly uses the transactionscope to enhance the Excecute performance, based on the more recent and better answers in this thread.

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope()) 
{
    Connection.Open();
    Connection.Execute(sqlQuery, parameters);

    scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: The using keyword automatically calls IDispose which calls .Close(). The using keyword converts your code at compile time into a try/finally where .Dispose() is called in the finally.

Comment: I thought IDispose only called Dispose?

Comment: You are correct. It calls Dispose but the connections implementation of Dispose calls Close(). I am also assume that's a SqlConnection object. But yeah the using helps so you don't forget to call closed as it's called in Dispose.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Execute` method with only one insert statement will never do a bulk insert or be efficient. Even the accepted answer with a `Transaction` doesn't do a `Bulk Insert`.

If you want to perform a `Bulk Insert`, use the `SqlBulkCopy` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy

You will not find anything faster than this.

### Dapper Plus

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Dapper Plus](http://dapper-plus.net/)

This project is not free but offers all bulk operations:

- BulkInsert
- BulkUpdate
- BulkDelete
- BulkMerge

(Use under the hood `SqlBulkCopy`)

And some more options such as outputting identity values:

```
// CONFIGURE & MAP entity
DapperPlusManager.Entity<Order>()
                 .Table("Orders")
                 .Identity(x => x.ID);

// CHAIN & SAVE entity
connection.BulkInsert(orders)
          .AlsoInsert(order => order.Items);
          .Include(x => x.ThenMerge(order => order.Invoice)
                         .AlsoMerge(invoice => invoice.Items))
          .AlsoMerge(x => x.ShippingAddress);
```

Our library supports multiple providers:

- SQL Server
- SQL Compact
- Oracle
- MySql
- PostgreSQL
- SQLite
- Firebird

Comment: Emphasis on "not free" - Dapper Plus starts at $799 for use by one developer

Answer (score -3):

the fastest variant for me:

```
            var dynamicParameters = new DynamicParameters();
            var selects = new List<string>();
            for (var i = 0; i < members.Length; i++)
            {
                var member = members[i];
                var pUsername = $"u{i}";
                var pIsActive = $"a{i}";
                dynamicParameters.Add(pUsername, member.Username);
                dynamicParameters.Add(pIsActive, member.IsActive);
                selects.Add("select @{pUsername},@{pIsActive}");
            }
            con.Execute($"insert into Member(Username, IsActive){string.Join(" union all ", selects)}", dynamicParameters);
```

which generate sql like:

```
INSERT TABLENAME (Column1,Column2,...)
 SELECT @u0,@a0...
 UNION ALL
 SELECT @u1,@a1...
 UNION ALL
 SELECT @u2,@a2...
```

this query works faster because sql adds set of rows instead adding 1 row at a time. The bottleneck is not writing the data, it's writing what you're doing in the log.

Also, look into the rules of minimally logged transactions.

Comment: @m0sa, I fixed it :)