# Implementing a Lightweight TransactionScope

Tags: c#, ado.net, transactionscope, dapper, micro-orm

I'm referring to this SO question:
[Bulk inserts taking longer than expected using Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689779/bulk-inserts-taking-longer-than-expected-using-dapper)

and to this @SamSaffron comment to that question:

*"TransactionScope does a bunch of DTC nonsense you generally do not care about, would avoid it unless I needed that feature, it is quite easy to roll your own context attached to thread local storage"*

I know how to roll my own TransactionManager by using a transaction attached to a `[ThreadStatic]` variable, but is there some reliable way to **emulate** the `TransactionScope` so the commands will enlist automatically my transaction? The final product will be a transaction scope withour any MSDTC plumbing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see my [TextMetal](http://code.google.com/p/textmetal/) project, the sample code, and pay attention to the Plumbing namespace. If you have questions, email me. No MSDTC slight of hand, just ADO.NET, a unit of work pattern, and some well engineered data access code!

Comment: +1 it is a nice and interesting implementation, but ( may be I'm wrong) I can have more than one transaction in a single unit of work. If I get your code properly you have a one by one relation wit uow and transaction. hanks anyway, mor einterested in hacking the transaction scope class

Comment: A unit of work by definition implies one transaction. Sounds like what you are really saying is that you have multiple connections to data sources in a single unit of work, thus you need distributed transactions. My implementation assumes no MSDTC transactions.