# Executing Insert Statement with Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper, insert-into

I am trying to use the method explained by @MarcGravell in the below post and comments

[How to insert a C# List to database using Dapper.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150542/how-to-insert-a-c-sharp-list-to-database-using-dapper-net)

I am trying to go from

```
        string sql2 = string.Format(@"INSERT INTO #cusipSedolList (cusipSedol) values (@A)");

        IDbConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);

        using (con)
        {
            con.Open();
            foreach (var cusipSedol in cusipSedolsParameter)
            {
                con.Execute(sql2, new { A = cusipSedol.CusipSedol });
            }

        }
```

to

```
        string sql2 = string.Format(@"INSERT INTO #cusipSedolList (cusipSedol) values (@CusipSedol)");

        IDbConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);

        using (con)
        {
            con.Open();
            con.Execute(sql2, new {cusipSedolsParameter});

        }
```

with

```
       var cusipSedolsParameter = new List<CusipSedols>();

       public class CusipSedols
       {
           public string CusipSedol { get; set; }
       }
```

but I am getting the error that I have to declare @CusipSedol if it has more than one CusipSedol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second example, you pass the argument `new {cusipSedolsParameter}` which is an anonymous type object with a single member named `cusipSedolsParameter`.

Instead, you just want to pass your list.  Your call should look like:

`con.Execute(sql2, cusipSedolsParameter);`

Then Dapper will enumerate over your list and perform your query for each entry, matching query parameters against the properties of the type of the entry.

Comment: I changed it to queryResults = con.Query<SecData>(sqlNew, cusipSedolsParameter);but I still get the error: Must declare the scalar variable "@CusipSedol".

Comment: @eltropico it should work fine; can you confirm that `CusipSedol` is a **public property**, not a field, and not `internal`, `protected` or `private` ?

Comment: @Marc thank you very much for your help. It is working now. The reason it didn't work was a select statement right after the insert into statement in the same sql string in my actual code. Thank you for conforming that my posted logic was correct so I was able to find the mistake.