# How do I insert multiple records using Dapper while also including other dynamic parameters?

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

Here is a truncated example of what I'm trying to do:

```cs
var stuffTOSave = new List<SomeObject> {
    public int OtherTableId { get; set; }
    public List<Guid> ComponentIds { get; set; }
};

var sql = @"CREATE TABLE Components( ComponentId uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY )
INSERT INTO Components VALUES (@WhatGoesHere?)

SELECT * FROM OtherTable ot
JOIN Components c on c.ComponentId = ot.ComponentId
WHERE Id = @OtherTableId

DROP TABLE Components"

Connection.Execute(sql, stuffToSave);
```

I know from [other SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150542/how-to-insert-a-c-sharp-list-to-database-using-dapper-net) that you can pass a list into an insert statement with Dapper, but I can't find any examples that pass a list as well as another parameter (in my example, `OtherTableId`), or that have a non-object list (`List<Guid>` as opposed to a `List<SomeObject>` that has properties with names to reference).

For the second issue, I could select the `ComponentId`s into a list to give them a name like:

```
stuffToSave.ComponentIds.Select(c => new { ComponentId = c })
```

but then I'm not sure what to put in my sql query so that dapper understands to get the `ComponentId` property from my list of `ComponentIds` (Line 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would still like to know the real way of accomplishing this, but I have this workaround that uses string interpolation:

```cs
var sql = $@"CREATE TABLE Components( ComponentId uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY )
    INSERT INTO Components VALUES ('{string.Join($"'),{Environment.NewLine}('", request.ComponentIds)}')

    SELECT * FROM OtherTable ot
    JOIN Components c on c.ComponentId = ot.ComponentId
    WHERE Id = @OtherTableId

    DROP TABLE Components"
```

I'm not worried about SQL Injection since this is just interpolating a list of Guids, but I'd rather avoid this method if possible.