# How to use SQL Bulk Copy with Dapper .Net ?

Tags: c#, .net, dapper, sqlbulkcopy

I am working with Dapper .net for Bulk insert operation in SQL Tables. I am thinking to user SQKBulk copy with Dapper .Net but don't have any experience How to use SqlbulkCopy with Dapper .Net

your help is Highly appreciated

Comment: This question seems to be too broad. Is there a specific problem you are struggling with? If so, could you show the code of that problem?

Comment: just execute the sql script you have ,using  connection.execute(yoursqlquery)

Answer (score 1):

It is not good idea to use dapper for bulk insert, because there it will not fast. The better case for this is use of [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) class. But if you want use Dapper for bulk insert, you can find solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689779/bulk-inserts-taking-longer-than-expected-using-dapper).

Comment: SqlBulkCopy is great, but AFAIK only exists in System.Data.SqlClient data provider, so that's an with MS SQL server. Dapper, on the other hand, is data provider independent.