# Insert many rows with Dapper

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, dapper, sqlconnection

what's the best solution to insert many rows into the SQL Server with Dapper?
When I have got about 8k records my databaseconnection timeouts and fails.

In my application at the end stage I have got lets say a list of tables, where each table got list of rows.

What i do is creating transaction and foreaching on each table and then foreaching on each row and conn.CreateCommand, filling parameters and executeNonQuery. So if I got 9k records I am actually doing 9k executeNonQuery operations.

Is there any better option for me?

Comment: i would investigate using SqlBulkCopy with dapper. Maybe this references could help you: [Bulk inserts taking longer than expected using Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689779), [How to use SQL Bulk Copy with Dapper .Net ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070108)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agree with DaniCE, SqlBulkCopy is the way to go here. Been in that situation lately where I did most of the data work with dapper but with larger amounts of data, in my case millions of records, Dapper was for once not my best friend.

```
    private void BulkCopy(SqlConnection sqlConnection,string tableName, DataTable dataTable)
    {
        using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
            bulkCopy.BatchSize = 50000;
            bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 60; //seconds

            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks man, never heard about bulk insert neither SqlBuklCopy class. Just made some research about this topic after your post, and thats excatly what I need!! Thanks again !!

Answer (score 0):

The best free way is without a doubt `SqlBulkCopy` as @JFM and @DaniCE suggested

---

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Dapper Plus](http://dapper-plus.net/)

This library is **NOT FREE** but provides easy support for the following operations:

- BulkInsert
- BulkUpdate
- BulkDelete
- BulkMerge
- BulkSynchronize

By using mapping and allow to output value like identity columns.

```
// CONFIGURE & MAP entity
DapperPlusManager.Entity<Order>()
                 .Table("Orders")
                 .Identity(x => x.ID);

// CHAIN & SAVE entity
connection.BulkInsert(orders)
          .AlsoInsert(order => order.Items);
          .Include(x => x.ThenMerge(order => order.Invoice)
                         .AlsoMerge(invoice => invoice.Items))
          .AlsoMerge(x => x.ShippingAddress);
```

Comment: connection.BulkInsert(models).AlsoBulkInsert(model => model.SelectMany(c => c.Variables)); If you notice AlsoBulkInsert is a list, in your example it's not. Am I missing a using statement?