# Transactional operations simultaneously mixed with non-transactional ones

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, transactions, transactionscope

I need to perform data import from external source to my database. Because there is a lot of data to download, the import is executing for a long time and I need to persist periodic updates about current importing state to the database (for the user to follow).

Suppose I have 2 tables: `Import` (storage for imported data) and `Status` (importing state monitoring table).

The code for data import:

```
public class Importer
{
    public delegate void ImportHandler(string item);
    public event ImportHandler ImportStarted;

    public void OnStart(string item)
    {            
        ImportStarted(item);
    }

    public void Execute(string[] items)
    {
        foreach (var item  in items)
        {
            OnStart(item);                    
            PersistImportedData(Download(item));
        }
    }

    private void PersistImportedData(object data)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection()){ /*saving imported data*/ }
    }
}
```

The starter code - for invoking import task and updating its status:

```
public class Starter
{
    public void Process(string[] items)
    {
       var importer = new Importer();
       importer.ImportStarted += UpdateImportState;
       importer.Execute(items);
    }

    private void UpdateImportState(string item)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection()){ /*status updates*/ }
    }
}
```

Now everything works fine. Import is executing and user is getting status updates (from `Status` table) as import goes on.

The problem occurs because such logic is not safe. I have to be sure, that import is an atomic operation. I don't want partially downloaded and saved data. I've used transaction approach as a solution for this (I've wrapped `importer.Execute` with `TransactionScope`):

```
importer.ImportStarted += UpdateImportState;
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    importer.Execute(items);
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Now I have safety - rollback occurs e.g. in case of process abort.

**I faced different problem now - the one I want to resolve**. I need status updates information for the user to show, but the `Status` table is not affected by updates, while transaction is not yet completed. Even if I try to use `RequiresNew` option for creating separate transaction (not ambient one), nothing changes. The `Execute` function creates its own connection to database and `UpdateImportState` does the same. The connection is not shared. I don't know why `State` table cannot be affected, even if `TransactionScope` covers only logic connected with `Import` table.

How to preserve consistent import and allow periodic status updates ?

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2886326/1402923) on TransactionScope behaviour might be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TransactionScopeOption.Suppress in UpdateImportState instead of TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew

Comment: The scope has to stay as is around `importer.Execute()` because it needs to be atomic unit of work. Indeed `Suppress` option for new scope added to `UpdateImportState` solved the issue. BTW: Do you know why scope with `RequiresNew` option prevents outer logic from affecting database ? I thought it creates new transaction and forgets about what is going elsewhere (detach current transaction). It seems like outer logic has to be marked with new scope with `Suppress` option now.