# TransactionScope doesn't rollback transactions

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, rollback, transactionscope

I guess I'm doing it all wrong but did not find practicle examples to prove the theory.

I have the following code

### BusinessLayer

```
public static void AddEntities(ENTITY entity, int nb) {
    using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < nb ; i++) {
            DAL.AddEntity(entity);
        }
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

### DataAccessLayer

```
public static void AddEntity(entity) {
    using(SqlCommand command = ...) {
        // code
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

If an exception is thrown and multiple entities have already been persisted, they are not rollback. But the rest is not persisted also. I need everything to get persisted or nothing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884863/under-what-circumstances-is-an-sqlconnection-automatically-enlisted-in-an-ambien

Comment: @MitchWheat Thanks mitch this has been helpful